# Changing an image path in a Genesis function - from the '/images/' folder to the Media Library

Tags: php, wordpress, header, responsive, genesis

I'm tinkering with some code in a Genesis functions.php file, trying to figure out a way to replace the section of code below that pulls the header image as: `<img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/header.jpg" alt="%s"/>`).

The code itself works beautifully for a full-width responsive header, but the image must be placed in the child theme's images folder and I need a way to change the image path so that it is pulled from the `WordPress Dashboard > Customize > Header Image > Add New > (Media Library).`

Basically I need a workaround so I can have it pull from images uploaded via the WordPress Customizer instead of placing an image directly into the images folder of the child theme.

My goal is to make it as user friendly as possible for a 'not-at-all-techy' client, so I'm trying to customize the theme to allow image changes from the dashboard/customize feature rather than FTP because they want an easy way to change the header image often, right from the dashboard.

I'm not even sure it can be done, but any ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
add_filter( 'genesis_seo_title', 'filter_genesis_seo_site_title', 10, 2 );
function filter_genesis_seo_site_title( $title, $inside ){ 
    $child_inside = sprintf( '<a href="%s"><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/header.jpg" alt="%s"/></a>', trailingslashit( home_url() ), esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ), esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ), esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) );
    $title = str_replace( $inside, $child_inside, $title );
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you set up custom header support in child theme `functions.php`? i.e.

```
add_theme_support( 'genesis-custom-header', array( 'width' => 960, 'height' => 100 ) );
```

The codex has more info about [Custom Headers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers).

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks for replying! I have tried it with custom header support, but I can't keep it truly responsive on certain screens, even though most of the responsiveness is handled in the CSS. I've gotten it pretty close, but on some screens the html pushes min-heights that mess it up with excess background space. Even with overriding the html with !important, I can't clear the entire white-space area that appears behind/around/bordering the image. It's like the browser just gives up accepting the forced height at some point.